# Pattern-finding game

Tags: c#, game, winforms

This is a game that is supposed to be based on strategy and guessing.

The letters need to match in a ABCD fashion on each button on `buttons[0]` - `buttons[3]` ... and `buttons[n]` - `buttons[n]` in each square, kind of like a matrix, although there is no matrix math involved.

This is how the game starts:

[image: Initial state - showing 4 groups of 4 buttons, bottom-left group highlighted in green]

Each time a user clicks the "A" button, the buttons' text changes for all the `buttons[n]` in the ABCD sequence, and to win you need to match each square of controls to the ABCD sequence.

[image: Winning screen - showing identical pattern in all 4 button groups]

Any help in how to improve this code is welcome. Most of it is just code for WinForms, but the implementation of `checkForWins` really feels like it can be done better.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[] buttons = new Button[16];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            grid();
            MessageBox.Show("Find the pattern");
        }

        public void grid() {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {
                buttons[i] = new Button();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                buttons[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(HighLightm1);
                buttons[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(unhighlightm1);
            }

            for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
                buttons[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(highlightm2);
                buttons[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(unhighlightm2);
            }


            for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
                buttons[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(highlightm3);
                buttons[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(unhighlightm3);
            }


            for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
                buttons[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(highlightm4);
                buttons[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(unhightlightm4);
            }


            buttons[0].Parent = this;
            buttons[0].Location = new Point(10, 10);
            buttons[0].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[0].Click += new EventHandler(button1click);
            buttons[1].Parent = this;
            buttons[1].Location = new Point(70, 10);
            buttons[1].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[1].Click += new EventHandler(button2click);
            buttons[2].Parent = this;
            buttons[2].Location = new Point(10, 70);
            buttons[2].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[2].Click += new EventHandler(button3click);
            buttons[3].Parent = this;
            buttons[3].Location = new Point(70, 70);
            buttons[3].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[3].Click += new EventHandler(button4click);


            buttons[4].Parent = this;
            buttons[4].Location = new Point(140, 10);
            buttons[4].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[4].Click += new EventHandler(button5click);
            buttons[5].Parent = this;
            buttons[5].Location = new Point(200, 10);
            buttons[5].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[5].Click += new EventHandler(button6click);
            buttons[6].Parent = this;
            buttons[6].Location = new Point(140, 70);
            buttons[6].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[6].Click += new EventHandler(button7click);
            buttons[7].Parent = this;
            buttons[7].Location = new Point(200,70);
            buttons[7].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[7].Click += new EventHandler(button8click);


            buttons[8].Parent = this;
            buttons[8].Location = new Point(10, 140);
            buttons[8].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[8].Click += new EventHandler(button9click);
            buttons[9].Parent = this;
            buttons[9].Location = new Point(70, 140);
            buttons[9].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[9].Click += new EventHandler(button10click);
            buttons[10].Parent = this;
            buttons[10].Location = new Point(10, 200);
            buttons[10].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[10].Click += new EventHandler(button11click);
            buttons[11].Parent = this;
            buttons[11].Location = new Point(70, 200);
            buttons[11].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[11].Click += new EventHandler(button12click);


            buttons[12].Parent = this;
            buttons[12].Location = new Point(140, 140);
            buttons[12].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[12].Click += new EventHandler(button13click);
            buttons[13].Parent = this;
            buttons[13].Location = new Point(200, 140);
            buttons[13].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[13].Click += new EventHandler(button14click);
            buttons[14].Parent = this;
            buttons[14].Location = new Point(140, 200);
            buttons[14].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[14].Click += new EventHandler(button15click);
            buttons[15].Parent = this;
            buttons[15].Location = new Point(200, 200);
            buttons[15].Size = new Size(60, 60);
            buttons[15].Click += new EventHandler(button16click);
        }

        public void button1click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            buttons[0].Text = "D";
            buttons[1].Text = "A";
            buttons[2].Text = "B";
            buttons[3].Text = "C";
        }
        public void button2click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            buttons[0].Text = "C";
            buttons[1].Text = "D";
            buttons[2].Text = "A";
            buttons[3].Text = "B";

        }
        public void button3click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            buttons[0].Text = "B";
            buttons[1].Text = "C";
            buttons[2].Text = "D";
            buttons[3].Text = "A";
        }
        public void button4click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            buttons[0].Text = "A";
            buttons[1].Text = "B";
            buttons[2].Text = "C";
            buttons[3].Text = "D";
            checkForWins();
        }

        public void button5click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            buttons[4].Text = "C";
            buttons[5].Text = "D";
            buttons[6].Text = "A";
            buttons[7].Text = "B";
        }
        public void button6click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[4].Text = "B";
            buttons[5].Text = "C";
            buttons[6].Text = "D";
            buttons[7].Text = "A";
        }
        public void button7click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[4].Text = "A";
            buttons[5].Text = "B";
            buttons[6].Text = "C";
            buttons[7].Text = "D";
            checkForWins();

        }
        public void button8click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[4].Text = "D";
            buttons[5].Text = "A";
            buttons[6].Text = "B";
            buttons[7].Text = "C";
        }

        public void button9click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            buttons[8].Text = "B";
            buttons[9].Text = "C";
            buttons[10].Text = "D";
            buttons[11].Text = "A";
        }
        public void button10click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[8].Text = "A";
            buttons[9].Text = "B";
            buttons[10].Text = "C";
            buttons[11].Text = "D";
            checkForWins();
        }
        public void button11click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[8].Text = "D";
            buttons[9].Text = "A";
            buttons[10].Text = "B";
            buttons[11].Text = "C";
        }
        public void button12click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[8].Text = "C";
            buttons[9].Text = "D";
            buttons[10].Text = "A";
            buttons[11].Text = "B";
        }
        public void button13click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[12].Text = "A";
            buttons[13].Text = "B";
            buttons[14].Text = "C";
            buttons[15].Text = "D";
            checkForWins();
        }
        public void button14click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[12].Text = "D";
            buttons[13].Text = "A";
            buttons[14].Text = "B";
            buttons[15].Text = "C";
        }
        public void button15click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[12].Text = "C";
            buttons[13].Text = "D";
            buttons[14].Text = "A";
            buttons[15].Text = "B";
        }
        public void button16click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[12].Text = "B";
            buttons[13].Text = "C";
            buttons[14].Text = "D";
            buttons[15].Text = "A";
        }

        public void checkForWins() {
            if (buttons[0].Text == "A" && buttons[1].Text == "B" && buttons[2].Text == "C" && buttons[3].Text == "D")
                if (buttons[4].Text == "A" && buttons[5].Text == "B" && buttons[6].Text == "C" && buttons[7].Text == "D")
                    if(buttons[8].Text == "A" && buttons[9].Text == "B" && buttons[10].Text == "C" && buttons[11].Text == "D")
                        if (buttons[12].Text == "A" && buttons[13].Text == "B" && buttons[14].Text == "C" && buttons[15].Text == "D") {
                            MessageBox.Show("You Won !");
                            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {
                                buttons[i].Text = "";
                            }
                        }
        }
        public void HighLightm1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
            }
        }
        public void unhighlightm1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

        public void highlightm2(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.Salmon;
            }
        }

        public void unhighlightm2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

        public void highlightm3(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++) { 
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            }
        }
        public void unhighlightm3(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

        public void highlightm4(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }
        }
        public void unhightlightm4(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Naming.

> ```
>     public partial class Form1 : Form
> ```

---

Make it a habit to **name things**.  Even `MainForm` or `GameForm` would have been nice.

*Naming is hard* though.

> *There are only [two hard things](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.*
>
> -- Phil Karlton

But really, it's worth even just *trying* to get right. Readable code loves good naming.

---

> ```
> public void grid()
> ```

Per [Method Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw(v=vs.71).aspx), method names in C# should be `PascalCase`, and should start with a verb.

---

## Partial.

> ```
>     public partial class Form1 : Form
> ```

The `Form1` class is `partial`: its definition is split between multiple files - in this case I'd wager the rest of the class is defined in the auto-generated `Form1.Designer.cs`.

That's where `InitializeComponent` is defined:

> ```
> public Form1()
> {
>     InitializeComponent();
>     //...
> }
> ```

If you navigate to that `.Designer.cs` generated code, you'll see this:

> ```
> /// <summary> 
> /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
> /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
> /// </summary>
> private void InitializeComponent()
> ```

The entire `grid()` method is the kind of code typically seen there. There's a reason a missing parameterless constructor and/or a call to `InitializeComponent()` in that constructor, breaks the designer: Visual Studio not only *generates*, but also *runs* this code.

By defining your buttons in the `InitializeComponent()` method, you effectively remove this UI boilerplate from the interesting code, and as a bonus the form designer starts looking very much like the runtime one.

I would have used the designer, and let that code be generated.

---

#### Layout.

Your layout doesn't scale. If you didn't use the designer at all, and haven't manually modified the `Form1.Designer.cs` file, then the user can resize the form and... totally wreck your UI.

Use the *Container* controls WinForms has to offer - in this case a `TableLayoutPanel` with fully anchored buttons would have greatly simplified the layout - here a 4x4 grid; the form's `MinSize` is set to 200x200:

[image: 200x200 grid]
[image: same grid, stretched horizontally. buttons resize to maintain the margins]

---

## Implementation.

This leaves us with the click handlers for the buttons, the `checkForWins()` method, and this:

> ```
> private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
> }
> ```

I don't see that handler registered anywhere. This tells me that you created the form, and then double-clicked the designer to bring up the code; that registered the `Load` event and added a handler stub, and now the code won't build if you remove it. Right? Use the *events* view in the *property window* to locate the form's `Load` event - and remove it from there. Then you can remove the handler and build.

Don't keep empty methods around. Dead code is confusing.

---

What's missing is an *abstraction level* here: your code has *16 buttons*, but the problem has *4 groups of 4 buttons*.

You could create a `UserControl` to represent a group of 4 buttons, the `TableLayoutPanel` can now be a 2x2 grid instead of 4x4. And it would be easier to get the proper margins, and each control would handle its own buttons.

The one can implement some *model* to centralize the state, and have each control (/group of 4 buttons) delegate their click handler logic to the actual form; that would be a good start IMO.